# Growl type notification on iPad/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uibuilder

Growl type notification on iPad/iPhone?  I want to show a non-modal/non-popup notification on top of an iPad application.

Growl's are a Mac OS X program that show little popup windows in the corner of the screen that dissappear after an amount of time or have a little x on them (to close sooner.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a tutorial for a sliding view](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/sliding-views-on-and-off-screen-creating-a-reusable-sliding-message-widget.html).

Answer (score 0):

A custom UIView I created [GCDiscreetNotificationView](https://github.com/gcamp/GCDiscreetNotificationView) will setup this pretty easily.