# What is growler and modal?

Tags: iphone, github

I am currently writing scenarios for the application. I came across these terms growler and modal. Can someone please explain what these term means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two types of notification:

- the [old one (growl)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4754876/6309): a Mac OS X program that show little popup windows in the corner of the screen that dissappear after an amount of time or have a little x on them
- the [new modal one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56718552/6309),  using the form and page sheet style can be dismissed with a pan down gesture, which [changed with ios13](https://sarunw.com/posts/modality-changes-in-ios13/)

[image]